# How to create a gallery with an ad block with flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to create a gallery which has a block for ads at the right side. The gallery images should float around the ad block. If possible, I would also like that the ad block doesn't "get buried" on smaller screens (or when it's collapsed in the desktop browser), but is shown as high up as possible.

But whatever I try, I can't flex my head around this problem. Wrapper boxes, justifying them in any possible way, using order etc didn't work.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper article {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    padding: 10px;
}

article {
    flex: 5;
}

.inner-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.video-box {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    height: 130px;
    width: 190px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.add-box {
    display: flex;
    height: 260px;
    width: 380px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: orangered;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <article>
        <h2>Videos</h2>
        <div class="inner-wrapper">
                <div class="add-box">Ads</div>
                <div class="video-box">1</div>
                <div class="video-box">2</div>
                <div class="video-box">3</div>
                <div class="video-box">4</div>
                <div class="video-box">5</div>
                <div class="video-box">6</div>
                <div class="video-box">7</div>
                <div class="video-box">8</div>
                <div class="video-box">9</div>
                <div class="video-box">10</div>
                <div class="video-box">11</div>
                <div class="video-box">12</div>
                <div class="video-box">13</div>
                <div class="video-box">14</div>
                <div class="video-box">15</div>
                <div class="video-box">16</div>
                <div class="video-box">17</div>
                <div class="video-box">18</div>
                <div class="video-box">19</div>
                <div class="video-box">20</div>
                <div class="video-box">21</div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Any solution except CSS grid (because it's less supported) is much appreciated.

Comment: inline-block element + float for the ads?

Comment: @rapstacke any progress on this? Is the JS library I suggested a possible solution?

Comment: @Barthy as far as I can judge it, JS seems to be the only solution. Flow doesn't seem to be able to float items around another flow-box. My solution is use 2 columns, 1 for the images on the left and 1 for the ads on the right, and then use a media query to rearrange the view for smaller screens by changing the `order` of the flex-boxes, i.e. that the ads appear first. The JS solution is the ecstatically better one, but I can't use it for simplicity and performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good use case for [`desandro/masonry`](https://masonry.desandro.com).

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
var msnry = new Masonry(elem, {
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  percentPosition: true
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper article {
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

article {
  flex: 5;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.video-box {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  height: 130px;
  width: 190px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.add-box {
  display: flex;
  height: 260px;
  width: 380px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: orangered;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <article>
    <h2>Videos</h2>
    <div class="inner-wrapper grid">
      <div class="grid-item add-box">Ads</div>
      <div class="grid-sizer grid-item video-box">1</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">2</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">3</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">4</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">5</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">6</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">7</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">8</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">9</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">10</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">11</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">12</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">13</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">14</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">15</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">16</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">17</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">18</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">19</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">20</div>
      <div class="grid-item video-box">21</div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Answer accepted because JS seems to be the only solution. A pure `flex-box` implementation doesn't seem to be able to produce the desired behavior.